# Multiple editor windows in Xcode

Tags: xcode

When coding in Xcode, I double-click a file in the "Groups and files" list, and it opens a new editor window. I have several of these open at once.

Until today.

Today, when I double-click a file in the list, it opens the file in the last editor window I was using, meaning I can only have one editor window up at any one time.

I guess I've switched some option somewhere by mistake. How do I get it back to the way I like it?

I'm using Xcode 3.2.5

Comment: Same here - this just started happening very recently - possibly related to the OS X 10.6.6 update ? You can still get at all the files using the forward/backward arrows but no separate windows now for some reason. Annoying.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the top right of the editing window is an icon that says "grouped", perhaps you clicked on it by accident.

Click on it so it says "ungrouped", and you'll be back to opening multiple windows.

Comment: Would you include a screenshot? I cannot find the "grouped" icon

Answer (score 1):

perhaps preferences>General>Open Counterpart in same Editor

Comment: I think this only applies when switching back and forth between corresponding .c and .h files (or equivalent).